# C# splitting a string with multiple seperator

Tags: c#, arrays

```
user1;user2;user3;user4 user1
```

I'd like to split these strings so I can iterate over all of them to put them in objects. I figured I could use

```
myString.split(";")
```

However, in the second example, there is no ; , so that wouldn't do the trick. What would be the best way to do this when it can be variable like this?

Thanks

Comment: @Mostafiz Why did you removed the new line?

Comment: ops question have no newline its space I think

Comment: @Mostafiz look at the previous edit diff, it's indeed a new line ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use overload taking multiple separators:

```
myString.Split(new[] { ";", " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for a regex. The split method can take a list of separators

```
"user1;user2;user3;user4 user1".Split(';', ' ')
```

outputs

```
string[5] { "user1", "user2", "user3", "user4", "user1" }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex

```
"[ ;]"
```

the square brackets define a *character class* - matches one of the characters between the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use overload of `Split()` method which take an array of seperator

```
string myString = "user1;user2;user3;user4 user1";
string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { ";", " " };
string[] s = myString.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

the following test pass!

```
    [TestCase("user1;user2;user3;user4 user1", 5)]
    public void SplitString(string input, int expectedCount)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedCount, input.Split(new []{";"," "},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
    }
```